# Many claims principles - how to access the non standard ones

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, claims-based-identity

New to claims, but i am currently getting the claims to use this data within my application..

I have around 200 claims in my principle object

```
[CascadingParameter]
        private Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationState> authState { get; set; }
        private System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal principal;

protected async override void OnParametersSet()
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.UtcNow;
            if (authState != null)
            {
                principal = (await authState).User;
            }
        }
```

For instance i have a claim that says {city:Norfolk} with a value property of "Norfolk" how do i access this individual claim in code...

Thanks in advance.

How to access the value.?

**

### I Managed to solve it

**

```
 string val =  principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "NameOfTypeHere").Value;
```

Comment: Glad you figured out your problem. You can post your solution as an answer and even mark it as the accepted answer. It will help others on the site in the future to do things this way.

Comment: How do i do that. thanks.

Comment: I use this page when I am debugging / exploring claims. https://github.com/BrianLParker/RoleBaseAuth/blob/master/RoleBaseAuth/Client/Pages/Claims.razor. I found it in the docs somewhere and adapted it.

Comment: @sinfella You can just write an answer down below where it says "Your Answer". That way your solution shows up in the answers section rather than as part of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out.

```
string val = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "NameOfTypeHere").Value;
```